# sum all values of a multidimensional array via month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra

I have the following data, and I want to sum all the `data` value via their month.

```
   [
    {"month":"Apr", "data": 1},
    {"month":"Apr", "data": 9},
    {"month":"May", "data": 2},
    {"month":"May", "data": 10},
    {"month":"May", "data": 2},
    {"month":"June", "data": 1},
   ]
```

So that the output should be like this

```
 [
    {"month":"Apr", "data": 10},
    {"month":"May", "data": 14},
    {"month":"June", "data": 1},
   ]
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you don't need such verbose data format. You can just do it with only 1 iteration:

```
data.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, v| h[v] = 0 }) do |elem, memo|
  memo[elem[:month]] += elem[:data] 
end
#=> {"Apr"=>10, "May"=>14, "June"=>1}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Is there any good source to learn ruby / sinatra?

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper it depends on what kind of learning you prefer (books, podcasts, blogs, courses etc).

Comment: I prefer learning via blogs or any learning website (free source).

Comment: `Hash.new(0)` would be sufficient here right? Might make the code a little more accessible to others coming to the question. (Nice answer btw, +1.)

Answer (score 1):

You can group the data by `month` with the help of `group_by` and the `sum` the values

```
data = [
  {"month":"Apr",  "data": 1},
  {"month":"Apr",  "data": 9},
  {"month":"May",  "data": 2},
  {"month":"May",  "data": 10},
  {"month":"May",  "data": 2},
  {"month":"June", "data": 1}
]

data.group_by{ |h| h[:month] }.map{ |k, v| { month: k, data: v.sum{ |h| h[:data] }}}

#=> [{:month=>"Apr", :data=>10},
#=> {:month=>"May", :data=>14},
#=> {:month=>"June", :data=>1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

While I was trying it myself. I was able to do it somehow. I am not sure if it's the best method, but it worked. Here I have also added empty months for example my above sample had Apr, May, June months and I needed rest of the months as well, so here is my code. 
 Here `arr` is an actual array from database as mentioned above in the sample and `month_list` contain a list of months starting from `Jan` to `Dec`

`arr` contain values like this

```
 [
         {"Month":"Apr", "data": 1},
        {"month":"Apr", "data": 9},
        {"month":"May", "data": 2},
        {"month":"May", "data": 10},
        {"month":"May", "data": 2},
        {"month":"June", "data": 1},
       ]
```

`month_list` contain empty values like this

```
[
    {"month":"Jan", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Feb", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Mar", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Apr", "data": 0},
    {"month":"May", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Jun", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Jul", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Aug", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Sep", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Oct", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Nov", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Dec", "data": 0},
   ]
```

The following function will club both the arrays and also sum all the data monthly

```
  def self.add_values_via_date(arr, month_list)
    a = []
    # create empty data
    month_list.each do |data|
      a << {:month=> data, :data=>0}
    end
    #sum all months data
    a.each do |data|
      arr.each do |value|
        if data[:month] == value[:month]
          data[:data] += value[:data]
        end
      end
    end
    return a
  end
```

and give me the output like this

```
[
    {"month":"Jan", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Feb", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Mar", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Apr", "data": 10},
    {"month":"May", "data": 14},
    {"month":"Jun", "data": 1},
    {"month":"Jul", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Aug", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Sep", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Oct", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Nov", "data": 0},
    {"month":"Dec", "data": 0},
   ]
```